# Jquery with google maps is not showing correctly

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-mobile

im trying to bind a googlemap in a website but it dont show the map correctly if I use jquery.

The source looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<title>Startseite</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css" /> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>

<!-- GoogleMaps !-->
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./js/jquery.ui.map.full.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    // Also works with: var yourStartLatLng = '59.3426606750, 18.0736160278';
    var yourStartLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(59.3426606750, 18.0736160278);
    $('#map_canvas').gmap({'center': yourStartLatLng});
  });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page" id="startseite">

  <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
    <h1>Titel</h1>
  </div>

  <!--<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">!-->
  <div data-role="tabs" id="tabs" >
    <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="left">
      <ul>
          <li><a href="#one" data-ajax="false" class="ui-btn-active" data-icon="search">tab1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#two" data-ajax="false" data-icon="location">Karte</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="one" class="ui-body-d ui-content">
      Page1
    </div>
    <div id="two" class="ui-body-d ui-content">
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 400px; position: relative" id="map_canvas"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So I'm getting this type of error:
[image: GoogleMap Error]

I'm new in this GoogleMaps thing so sorry if this is a simple question but I couldn't find a solution for it.

Comment: Map canvas's height is set to 400px, you need to set the height according to available space in page if you want it to occupy content div entirely without causing page to scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delay the initialization of the map until the first time the tab with the map is displayed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var map = null;

    $("#tabs").on("tabsactivate", function (event, ui) {
        if ((ui.newPanel.attr('id') == 'two') && !map) {
            var yourStartLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(59.3426606750, 18.0736160278);
            map = $('#map_canvas').gmap({'center': yourStartLatLng});
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tr6n9/1/)

Comment: Ok this solution works but only if I bind the script in the tabs area. Why it dont work if I bind the script in the head section?

Comment: @Kingalione - It works for me in the head section. I updated the code in my answer to show exactly what I have in the head section.

Answer (score 0):

```
         $(window).bind("load", function() {
                ShowMap();
             });
```

Just put all the map code in function, and call it after the page has loaded.  This happens because of jquery page delay in loading.  That means that the map loads before the page has loaded.

Answer (score -1):

You need to initialize google maps after tab with map will become visible. For example:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function (){
  $('[data-icon="location"]').parent().one('click', function (){ //click on tab link to open tab with map
        var yourStartLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(59.3426606750, 18.0736160278);
        $('#map_canvas').gmap({'center': yourStartLatLng});
  });
});
```